# Openweathermap api, getting a no apikey error, but I am supplying one

Tags: javascript, jquery, openweathermap

I am using the code below to get the weather for a city and am running into an error with the api key even though it is working, is there an ordering error here that I am missing?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnGetWeather').click(function () {
            var requestData = $('#txtCity').val() + ',' + $('#txtCountry').val();
            var resultElement = $('#resultDiv');

            $.ajax({
                'method': 'POST',
                'url': 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?',
                'data': {
                    'q': $('#txtCity').val() + ',' + $('#txtCountry').val(),
                    'APPID': 'e142d6277e3108bf30a12ab09c98ce6f',
                },
                'success': function (data) {
                    resultElement.html('Weather: ' + data.weather[0].main + '<br />' + 'Description: ' + data.weather[0].description);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I hope this is not your real API key. If it is you should request a new one immediately.

Comment: I will once its working, can't test it without